# Should I copy almost the whole question to ask an additional question?

Tags: discussion

I have written an ellaborate patient medical history and asked to explain one strange phenomenon ([Explanation of normal CRP during neutrophilia?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/explanation-of-normal-crp-during-neutrophilia)). Now it has been explained by Graham Chiu, I want to ask for help in explaining a decreased sedimentation on the same patient.

Should I start a discussion bellow [the answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/5606/3517) or should I copy the whole medical history and ask the different question? I am even considering turning it into a differential-diagnosis.